# Connect with facebook

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

I m conneting facebook using fbcoonect in iphone. When i login first time its give data but after logout of facebook and login with another account then also gives same data as per given last time.
My code here like -

```
- (void)session:(FBSession*)session didLogin:(FBUID)uid {
self.usersession =session;


NSString* fql = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                 @"select     uid,name,first_name,middle_name,last_name,birthday,email,pic_square from user where uid == %lld",self.usersession.uid];


[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fql
                            forKey:@"query"];
[[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self]
 call:@"facebook.fql.query" params:params];
NSLog(@"User with id %lld logged in.", uid);
self.post=NO;}
```

and also i try like this code -

```
 - (void)session:(FBSession*)session didLogin:(FBUID)uid {
self.usersession =session;
NSLog(@"User with id %lld logged in.", uid);
[self getFacebookName];}

- (void)getFacebookName {
NSString* fql = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                 @"select uid,name,first_name,middle_name,last_name,birthday,email,pic_square from user where uid == %lld",self.usersession.uid];


NSDictionary* params =
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fql
                            forKey:@"query"];
[[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self]
 call:@"facebook.fql.query" params:params];
self.post=NO;   
}
```

but its hase same error. Please give solution.